# Removing items from one list when present in another in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i am trying below,

```
processed_files_list='file2 file6'
input_files='file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7'
for i in `echo $processed_files_list`
do
    echo "removing '$i'"
    input_files_new=${input_files//$i/}
done
echo $input_files_new
```

output:

```
removing 'file2'
removing 'file6'
[user@desk ~]$ echo $input_files_new
file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file7
```

but the above does not remove first portion, in this case it is **file2**...why this is happening?

Comment: sorry my initial answer was complete and utter gibberish.  what is actually happening is that on each invocation you are setting the value of input_files_new to the value of input_files with the current value of $i removed.  $input_files is never changed, at all, ever. so each time through the loop it gets the complete file list

Comment: @Cwissy: recommend deleting original comment.

Comment: Capturing the output of `echo` here is pointless; `for i in $processed_files` is sufficient.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for including a small and complete test case along with actual and expected output. +1

Comment: *grumbles about using strings as if they were lists*. Bash has real array support, and your code will behave much better in corner cases (such as dealing with filenames with spaces or literal newlines) if you use it.

Comment: and also how can i use regex for this to match exact word to remove?

Comment: @s.1234, why do you think a regex is the right tool for the job? So long as you enforce spaces at the start and end of your "lists", you can avoid the `file1`-matching-`file10` issue without needing any regex -- just match `[[:space:]]file1[[:space:]]` and replace it with `[[:space:]]` (a literal space is fine of course too; I'm writing it out as `[[:space:]]` here for clarity). Of course, that leaves you still having support for filenames with spaces being broken, or filenames containing literal glob characters... but that's why you *shouldn't be using strings at all* for this use case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thank you so much. I didn't know the capabilities of bash, it seems we can do so much like programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a better-practice approach which will work with names containing spaces, names containing wildcards, names which are substrings of other names, and other more bizarre corner cases:

```
processed_files_list=( file2 file6 )
input_files=( file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 )

# create an associative array with filenames as keys, and a fixed value
declare -A input_files_new=( ) # requires bash 4.0 or later
for f in "${input_files[@]}"; do
  input_files_new[$f]=1
done

# remove keys associated with files you don't want
for f in "${processed_files_list[@]}"; do
  unset "input_files_new[$f]"
done

# Print shell-quoted version of the keys from that associative array.    
printf '%q\n' "${!input_files_new[@]}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler version of your problem:

```
files="foo"
files_new="$files bar"
files_new="$files baz"
echo "$files_new"
```

This outputs

```
foo baz
```

So what happened to `bar`?

Those changes were overwritten because you copied and modified the original list instead of your working list. Therefore, you only see the latest change instead of accumulated changes.

You can fix that by first setting

```
input_files_new="$input_files"
```

and then updating that list each time:

```
input_files_new=${input_files_new//$i/}
```

However, you should really consider using proper arrays, because replacing `file1` in your string would also affect `file10`.